# Infor EAM extensible framework

Tags: javascript, extjs, infor-eam

How to set field value based on another field using extensible framework

Field.formPanel.setFldValue(”field_name”, “fieldValue”, true);

Answer (score 0):

Can use form predefined methods

```
formRef.getForm().setValues({field_name, 'fieldValue'});
```

**or**

```
formRef.loadRecord(modelData) - if values data is Model Instance
```

**or**

```
formRef.down('isFormField[name='+'field_name'+']').setValue('field_value')
```